# Is there an easier way to access Json Object values in Jarray

Tags: c#, json, json.net

ok so I've just started learning c# and I'm re-creating a program I made in python which uses an api to pull in student records and uses the json data to make new user accounts.

Now I Know python has lots of "Magic" features and it's designed to be quick and easy. But there must be an easier way for me to access the json object values in c#

an example in Python to filter out my data for students whose date of entry = today i simply need

```
for st in student:  # for every student, if DateOfEntry = today add to csv file
if (st['DateOfEntry'])[:10].strip() == today.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'):
```

now in c# from the resources ive found online on Jarray to access i need to do something like this

```
JArray students = JArray.Parse(response.Content);

foreach (JObject student in students.Children<JObject>())
    {
    foreach (JProperty studentProperty in student.Properties())
        {
        string propertyName = studentProperty.Name;
        if (propertyName.Equals("DateOfEntry"))
            {
            string propertyValue = (string)studentProperty.Value;
            //Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Value: {1}", propertyName, propertyValue);
            if (propertyValue.Equals(today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")))
                {
                }
```

Now I want to create a list of lists of student details by picking out certain key values i.e name, id, year etc

in python it was as simple as placing the following in the if statement from earlier

```
stu = (
        st['Forename']+' '+ st['Surname']+'<br><br>',
      )
    newstudents.append(stu)
```

But with my current c# setup it would like like I would have to re-iterate over studentporoperty or throw in some more if statements to retrieve the property values I want.

this feels clunky and just not right, and if I've learnt anything its "if it feels wrong then you are probably doing it wrong"

I'm wondering if parsing the JSON to a JArray is even the right thing to do at this point or if there is an easier way to access the keys and values?

Comment: Are you really using C# language version 2.0? Do you mean either .Net Core 2.0 or .Net Standard 2.0, instead?

Comment: The *easy* way is to deserialize the entire string into objects, not access items one by one. You could write a simple `var students=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student[]>(json)` to get a strongly typed array of student objects. Dates have no format, they are binary values.

Comment: You can generate the necessary classes easily by copying a JSON example and pasting it into a C# file with `Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes`.

Comment: @phuzi I am using .netcore 2.2  so probably not c#2.0 I thought they were the same, my bad

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos that is cool, did not know you could do that, however each student has loads of json data and i only need say 5-12 parts of it

Comment: @JP_ can u please post your json content in the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using Json NewtonSoft, it will greatly simplify the deserialization of your Json and then the use of your student list.
Linq would have been handy in your case but it is available only from C # 3.0.

I give you a simple example of using NewtonSoft (to take in Nuget package).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass object1 = new MyClass(1, "A", new DateTime(2019, 1, 1));
        MyClass object2 = new MyClass(2, "B", new DateTime(2019, 1, 2));

        List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
        myList.Add(object1);
        myList.Add(object2);

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myList);
        List<MyClass> objectAfterJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(json);

        int id = objectAfterJson[0].Id;
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public DateTime Date;

    public MyClass(int id, string name, DateTime date)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Date = date;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try this, however as I hadn't set it up as a class it didn't work, I saw plenty of other examples on newtonsoft for this but it just didn't click in my brain, also the thought of creating a class for it seemed unnecessary as im used to Python...Thanks though!